# Click/touch img to fadeToggle div not working in chrome mobile on pixel

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, touch, mobile-chrome

just like the tittle says. It works several OS and all the iPhone range, several browsers, but testing it on my Pixel using chrome it does not work. Using my phone it works with opera mini and firefox.

HTML:

```
    <div class="contact-box row">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Abaladi%C3%A7a-Algarve-Craft-Beer-797257403729657/" target="_blank">
            <img class="fb-icon icon" src="./resources/icons/Facebook.svg" alt="facebook">
        </a>
        <img class="mail-icon icon" src="./resources/icons/Email.svg" alt="email">
```

jQuery

```
var msg = $('.mail-icon');

var form = $('.form-box');

msg.on('click touchstart', function() {
    form.fadeToggle();
    return false;
});
```

[Abaladica](http://abaladica.beer)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var msg = $('.mail-icon');
var form = $('.form-box');
$("body").on("click touchstart", ".contact-box .mail-icon", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    form.fadeToggle();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: still the same... I've added the url in case someone wants to debug in their pixel.

Answer (score 0):

After remote debugging problem was that jquery cdn wasnt loading fast enough. Just changed it to googleapis cdn and it is working now.